# Окрас или окраска?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Религиозный  окрас, оправдание и прикрытие псевдорелигиозными лозунгами многократно усугубляет любой общественный конфликт.
Если не трогать "кривизну" предложения в целом, то можно ли в данном контексте использовать слово "окрас", или лучше - "окраска"?

Comment: Как и окрас (фон, пафос), так и оправдание с прикрытием... А где то, что окрашивается, оправдывается, прикрывается? Кривизну надо править первым делом.

Comment: Не хочется (да и не в моей компетенции) писать тексты за авторов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фрагмент текста  http://dumrf.ru/upravlenie/speeches/14674

**Религиозный окрас, оправдание и прикрытие псевдорелигиозными лозунгами многократно усугубляет любой общественный конфликт.** Усугубляет и подогревает чувство высокомерия и превосходства человека одной расы, культуры, религии над представителями иных групп, подогревает представление о том, что представители определенных социальных групп обладают бОльшей ценностью, нежели представители других, те или иные культуры превосходят иные культуры.

**Вариант редактирования первого предожения:**

Религиозная окраска **разногласий**, оправдание и прикрытие **своих действий** псевдорелигиозными лозунгами многократно усугубляет любой общественный конфликт.

**Окрас или окраска?**

В словаре **переносное значение** зафиксировано только для слова ***окраска***.

**ОКРАС**, м. **Спец. Цвет, окраска** (шерсти животного, оперения птиц и т.п.).

**ОКРАСКА**, 3. **Особый характер**, приобретаемый чем-л. под влиянием чего-л., особый оттенок, сообщаемый чему-л. кем-, чем-л. Мечты о путешествиях приобрели особую окраску. Любовь с романтической окраской.

Пример: В одних случаях нефтяным войнам придается **религиозная окраска**... [Леонид Медведко. // «Дружба народов», 1999]

В то же время в ряде случаев используется и слово ***окрас***, например: Иноземная колонизация имела **пестрый этнический окрас** ... [Петр Скоробогатый. // «Эксперт», 2014]